# Insertion of many to many relationship in database gives me a Call to a member function sync() on null

Tags: arrays, laravel, many-to-many

I have a `many to many` relationship.

`Quote Model`

```
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

`Product Model`

```
public function quotes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Quote::class);
}
```

I receive details from an input form to my `Controller`. The output is as follows:

```
array:39 [▼ 
"_token" => "NgcHxCjpGUe1ot8nJr4Z8VFuA3DG9VprKWqRu5yk"
"quote_id" => "52" 
20 => "0"
10 => "0"
11 => "0"
12 => "0"
13 => "0"
14 => "0"
15 => "0"
16 => "0"
17 => "0"
```

The `"quote_id"` refers to the quote created in a step preceding the input form mentioned above. The `quote_id` is passed to the controller from a hidden input field in the form. In the array above the `$key` refers to the `product_id` and the `$value` refers to the quantity of the product.

I am trying to insert the data into a `table` `product_quote`.

```
Schema::create('product_quote', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('quote_id');
        $table->integer('qty');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Here is the code I have:

```
$data = $request->toArray();
$quote_id = $data['quote_id'];
    unset($data['quote_id']);
    $quote = Quote::query()->findOrFail($quote_id);
    foreach (array($data) as $key => $value){
        $quote->products->sync($data);
        $quote->save();
    }
```

There after I still need to add the product quantity but I am getting an error: Call to a member function sync() on null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding of Collections vs Relations.

In Laravel if you have the relation products in your case, to access the relation you will call.

```
$quote->products(); // returns belongsToMany relation query
```

To access the collection you access it as a property.

```
$quote->products; // returns a collection with the products
```

In your case, you are accessing it as a Collection. Thou you are getting a null error something else could be wrong, but start by changing it to the following.

Secondly to set pivot fields use key value array on the sync call, using the key and the value from your structure. You should probably also unset the token. Instead i filter it by using except. A better approach is to use validated on a form request.

You will need to adjust your data to fit the expected key value structure on the sync call, sync should also only be called one as it synchronizes the data between each call.

```
$data = $request->toArray();

$quote = Quote::findOrFail($data['quote_id']); // calling query() is unnecessary

$products = collect($request->except(['_token', 'quote_id']))->
    ->mapWithKeys(function($item, $key) {
        return [$key => ['qty' => $item]];
    })->all();

$quote->products()->sync($products);
```

This solution utilises mapWithKeys, which lets you control the key and the item in the collection, which is a collection method not used that often. The return of the closure should be in the format `return ['key' => 'item'];` instead of `return 'item';`

Comment: Firstly I have to thank you. I now at least get an entry into the `product_quote` table. However it is only one entry. It does get the following correct on that one entry. 
1) The `product_id`
2) The `quote_id`
3) The `qty`

But apart from only getting one entry, the `id` is not correct, the first entry was `id = 33`, same as the product_id that does get entered into the database..

The second entry was `id = 66` and the 3rd was `id = 132`.

I did a `dd()` on the variable $data and the `product_id` of 33 is the last entry I get from my input form. Any suggestion why?

Comment: oh wait :) sync deletes all entries inbewteen calls. Will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked. I do apply some logic with `if statements` after receiving the data from the form and these do not show in the `table`. But I assume it is because the are not part of $request, and I would need to add them to the array. I do wish you were my friend :) I am sitting here at 4am trying to figure this out and you saved me.

Comment: np man if you ever have trouble just comment here and link to a question i can always take a look at it :)

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63299397/updating-a-column-price-in-my-product-table-with-input-received-from-a-form)

Comment: [php, greedy, coin making](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63435315/php-greedy-algorythm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `products` relationships rather than the collection.

```php
$quote->products()->sync($data);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will look into what you have said so I can understand and not make the same mistake in the future.