# Updating a column price in my product table with input received from a form

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Thank you in advance for the assistance.

I have a table in my database. `Migration`.

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('group');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->double('price');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I retrieve all the products from the database and sort them according to the `group` in my `view`. The `input` `name = "{{id}}"` and `input` `value = "{{price}}"`

Please see my `form`:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{route('product.update')}}">
@csrf
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-ns_890-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#ns_890_main"
           role="tab" aria-controls="pills-ns_890" aria-selected="true">KX-NS890</a>
    </li>

</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="ns_890_main" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-ns_890-tab">
        @foreach($main_890 as $item)
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="{{$item->id}}" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{$item->code. ' ' .$item->name}}</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div >
                        <input name="{{$item->id}}" type="number" min="0" id="{{$item->id}}" class="form-control @error('{{$item->id}}') is-invalid @enderror"
                               value="{{$item->price}}" autocomplete="{{$item->id}}" required autofocus>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>

</div>




<div class="form-group row mb-0">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            {{ __('Save and Continue') }}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

After the form is submitted I get the following when I `dd($request)` in my `Controller`.

```
+request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#44 ▼
#parameters: array:187 [▼
  "_token" => "XdnsoU9sqtgYpwFAqGQRM2fTde6mYJhhwJL3a3R2"
  119 => "8461"
  120 => "9682"
  121 => "501"
  122 => "2008"
  123 => "16141"
  124 => "5385"
  125 => "9122"
  126 => "3310"
  127 => "1692"
  128 => "2811"
  129 => "1686"
  130 => "2811"
  131 => "1506"
  132 => "1064"
  133 => "4078"
  134 => "8329"
```

And `dd($request)` ends with the following:

```
  115 => "115"
  116 => "2660"
  117 => "730"
  118 => "8400"
  28 => "1200"
  29 => "75"
  30 => "95"
  31 => "68"
  32 => "243"
  33 => "474"
  202 => "56"
  203 => "1990"
  204 => "760"
  205 => "760"
  206 => "115"
```

The reason I am including the last part of the `dd($request)`, is that when the form is submitted it would take the value assigned to `119` which is `8461` but in the database updates the record `where` `id` is `206`, the last entry received from my form, so `206 => "115"` becomes `206 => "8461"`, this is the only record then updated in the database.

What I am trying to do is update the price column by id with the value received from the form.

Please see my code below:

```
$products = collect($request->except(['_token']))
        ->mapWithKeys(function($item, $key) {
            return [$key => ['price' => $item]];
        })->all();

    foreach ($products as $product){
        $id = collect($request->except(['_token']))->mapWithKeys(function ($item){
            return ['id' => $item];
        });

        DB::table('products')->
        where('id', $id)->
        update(array('price' => $product['price']));
```

Please be so kind as to let me know where I have fallen off of the wagon?

Comment: in my opinion, there is a better way to do this all, can you please post the form you are submitting?

Comment: Sure, I will add the form, it is rather long so I will take certain parts from it.

Comment: @Berto99 the form has been added above. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop the data and use Eloquent models to update the data. As i helped you in the other question, `mapWithKeys()` was to combat pivot table updates, you should often not use that one. As it is for very special conditions, here you can just loop it. I would always prefer eloquent models over DB::update().

```
foreach ($request->except(['_token']) as $id => $price) {
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $product->price = $price;
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: you make these things look so easy, I clearly need to keep practicing because I am over thinking this.

Comment: 4 years ago, i had a hard time finding answers on stackoverflow to answer because my skillset was so narrow. Things change when you practice :)

Comment: I'm allowed to suggest the edit, but there is a syntax error: `Product::find` instead of `Product:.find`.

Another note, this will fire observers too on the product. That might not be what you want.

Comment: Typo, i feel like DB:: calls should be made to a minimum, if you over abuse update calls, it can be hard to secure that observers actually fire in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

It can be simplified a lot like so:

```
collect($request->except(['_token']))->each(static function($item, $key) {
    return DB::table('products')->where('id', $key)->update([
        'price' => $item
    ]);
})
```

There is no need to do overcomplicate things with all this mapping you are doing, which ultimately leads to your issue you are experiencing. My guess is that the order of the mapping/request data is not the same, so when you do the second mapWithKeys in the foreach, it does not match with the current `$product` you are iterating over.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: pretty sure that this won't do what he is asking: _would take the value assigned to 119 which is 8461 but in the database updates the record where id is 206, the last entry received from my form, so 206 => "115" becomes 206 => "8461"_

Comment: From what I understand, the issue is that wrong ids are being updated. This is for sure due to the way he is mapping the data before updating it. I remove that mapping to avoid the wrong ids being updated.

Comment: As i read it, this is how i understand the problem too, especially how he describes building the form.